# coloring layer with sld based on mysql return value

Tags: mysql, openlayers, shapefile, geoserver, sld

Hello i'm trying to fill my wms layer using sld with return value from mysql. let's say i have population value which will be divided into 4 four categories. my map attributes only consist of polygon shapes and province. each province will have their own population. so if i want to color category 1 with red, 2=blue, 3=green , 4=black how can i do this? i mean is it possible to combine mysql with sld?

i have been able to fill the map because i add the attribute category within the map table. if there is solution plz tell me. if not is there any example how to change those attribute value within my map?
thank you